# Convert string to Time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a time that is 16:23:01. I tried using `DateTime.ParseExact`, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
string Time = "16:23:01"; 
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

lblClock.Text = date.ToString();
```

I want it to show in the label as 04:23:01 PM.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

"16:23:01" doesn't match the pattern of "hh:mm:ss tt" - it doesn't have an am/pm designator, and 16 clearly isn't in a 12-hour clock. You're specifying that format in the *parsing* part, so you need to match the format of the existing data. You want:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(Note the invariant culture, *not* the current culture - assuming your input genuinely always uses colons.)

If you want to *format* it to `hh:mm:ss tt`, then you need to put that part in the `ToString` call:

```
lblClock.Text = date.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Or better yet (IMO) use "whatever the long time pattern is for the culture":

```
lblClock.Text = date.ToString("T", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Also note that `hh` is unusual; typically you *don't* want to 0-left-pad the number for numbers less than 10.

(Also consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) API, which has a `LocalTime` type - a more appropriate match for just a "time of day".)

Answer (score 13):

```
string Time = "16:23:01";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Time, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

string t = date.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 6):

This gives you the needed results:

```
string time = "16:23:01";
var result = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
string test = result.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
//This gives you "04:23:01 PM"  string
```

You could also use `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")` as not all cultures will display AM/PM.

Answer (score -2):

The accepted solution doesn't cover edge cases.
I found the way to do this with 4KB script. Handle your input and convert a data.

Examples:

```
00:00:00 -> 00:00:00
12:01 -> 12:01:00
12 -> 12:00:00
25 -> 00:00:00
12:60:60 -> 12:00:00
1dg46 -> 14:06
```

You got the idea...
Check it https://github.com/alekspetrov/time-input-js