# Convert time in string format into time format

Tags: c#

I have time `"00.05.415"` (mm:ss.000) which is in `string` format.

I want to convert it to a `TIME` format where I can add multiple times such as `"00.05.415"+"00.06.415"+"00.07.415"` to get one single added time.

Comment: What language are you using? We'll definitely need to know that before moving forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919530/convert-string-to-time)

Comment: Is it an elapsed time value, such as you might measure in real life using a stopwatch?  Or is it a time of day value, such as you might observe in real life on a clock?  Those are two very different things.  (Note, the dup Avitus points at is for the latter.)

Comment: @MattJohnson it's an elapsed time. I'm getting these values from an XML node, thus in the string format. Is there anyway to convert string to time?

Comment: @Avitus, it's not a duplicate because you cannot easily parse that string into TimeSpan or DateTime.

Comment: So the question should start off as **I have _an elapsed_ time _of_ "00.05.415"** and....

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use TimeSpan.ParseExact so you can specify the format that the time is in and then you can add the time spans together:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TimeSpan span1 = Convert("00.05.415");
    TimeSpan span2 = Convert("00.07.415");

    TimeSpan result = span1 + span2;

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static TimeSpan Convert(string span)
{
    return TimeSpan.ParseExact(span, @"mm\.ss\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, if you aren't going to evaluate the result of the conversion, use `ParseExact`, not `TryParseExact`.

Comment: Fixed your invocation for you. :)  But the addition is correct and gives the correct value.

Comment: @MattJohnson How would you take an average of the timespan then?

Comment: @AnmolJaising TimeSpan avg = new TimeSpan(result.Ticks / numOfTimes);

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for all your help :D

Comment: @MattJohnson   Thanks for all your help :D

Comment: FYI - .NET Core 2.0 will have proper multiplication and division on `TimeSpan` without having to go through `Ticks` yourself.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7175

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the format is predefined to be `mm:ss.000` you can do following to parse to TimeSpan:

```
var strings = "00:05.415".Split(new []{'.', ':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var minutes = int.Parse(strings[0]);
var seconds = int.Parse(strings[1]);
var milliseconds = int.Parse(strings[2]);
var time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

And then you can add `TimeSpan`s together.

Comment: Why do all that parsing when there's `TimeSpan.ParseExact`?

Comment: @juharr, glad you asked. That's because when I tried `TimeSpan.ParseExact` I didn't escape periods and it didn't work for me. And then Tim posted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to take a look at the link that Avitus has and has the one [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'll have to ask why you'd want to add them together. [You can't really 'add' times together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077467/540174) .

One possible options is to to convert each to milliseconds and then formatting the resultant value.

5 seconds + 3.2 seconds could be:

```
5000 + 3200 = 8200.
```

You'd then use System.**TimeSpan** to convert that into days, hours, minutes ...etc

**thanks for the correction Matt**

Comment: I want to add them because i have a code extracting time from an XML running on 3 machines. So wanted to add those time and get the avg

Comment: Ok then I'd just convert them to DateTime > Milliseconds > add together than average out.

Comment: Do not use `DateTime` unless the times represent time of day.  Use `TimeSpan`

Comment: Your point about adding times together is why I asked what the time represents.  You certainly can add 1 minute + 1 minute = 2 minutes.  However, you cannot add 3 o'clock am + 5 o'clock pm because that's nonsense. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson , agreed. You can add periods of time, but not two different times.

Answer (score 0):

If your format is not predefined use this 4KB script https://github.com/alekspetrov/time-input-js

It converts string/number into time format HH:MM:SS

Examples

```
00:00:00 -> 00:00:00
12:01 -> 12:01:00
12 -> 12:00:00
25 -> 00:00:00
12:60:60 -> 12:00:00
1dg46 -> 14:06
["notatime"] -> 00:00:00 + console warn
```