# Reading from column custom value from Excel and parsing to DateTime or Time C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have problem with reading specific column from Excel, type of that column is custom and if I change type it changes values. So, I am not sure how to convert in code this to can use same value like in Excel.

For example in Excel this column looks like this:

```
    11:00
    12:00
    13:00
    14:00
      .
      .
      .
```

And now I want this to use in my code when I read excel file. But there is problem to compare with other hour, cause type of this column in excel is custom and if I change it to DateTime this change complete value?

I read value from Excel like this:

```
var loadTimeCell = (rangeSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919530/convert-string-to-time)

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ Hi, this does not help, cause even when I load from excel this start with only one zero, for example like this 0, instead of 00:00

Comment: So.. What does the data look like in `loadTimeCell` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard It is just zero (0), nothing else, but in first iteration it should be 00:00, cause like it is written in excel

Comment: What about the other cells; could do with a bit more to work with than "0", it being the default for lots of value types might mean nothing is being read at all

Comment: @CaiusJard Other cells are ok, cause they are not custom type in excel and I do not have problem with them.

Comment: So a simple "if 0 then" will resolve it?

Comment: @CaiusJard Where you mean if 0 then? Problem is cause I never get value in my code like it is in excel, so I will never have real value like 01:00 or 02:00 etc, this will always be 0 and 0 can be for 03:00, so I cant just change format..

Answer (score 0):

TimeValue Function should do it for you. This converts a text string to a time value. Something like this would do the job:

```
y = rangeSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 2].text
loadTimeCell = TimeValue(y)
```

Or you can also use this:

```
 var loadTimeCell = TimeValue(cstr((rangeSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2));
```

Comment: Thanks, but TimeValue does not exist at me. Is this for .NET, c#?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you're using for this, but you could try this alternate library that I maintain: [Sylvan.Data.Excel](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel), which should be able to read this data. Here is a complete C# 10 sample console app showing how to read values out of a time-only formatted column:

```
using Sylvan.Data.Excel;

var edr = ExcelDataReader.Create("data.xlsx");
// assumes a header row with column names.
var timeIdx = edr.GetOrdinal("Time");
while (edr.Read())
{
    // read the value as a DateTime. Date component will be 0001-01-01.
    var dt = edr.GetDateTime(timeIdx);
    // Get the time of day.
    var time = dt.TimeOfDay;
    Console.WriteLine(time);
}
```